# 400 Bad Request upload jar to Apache Flink

Tags: c#, .net, rest, apache-flink, dotnet-httpclient

I'm am getting a 400 Bad Request using the Flink RestApi to upload a jar file to the endpoint "/jars/upload" with c#, the endpoint definition is

> The jar must be sent as multi-part data. Make sure that the "Content-Type" header is set to "application/x-java-archive", as some http libraries do not add the header by default. Using 'curl' you can upload a jar via 'curl -X POST -H "Expect:" -F "jarfile=@path/to/flink-job.jar" http://hostname:port/jars/upload'.

And the documentation i'm following is: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/ops/rest_api/.

This is the error i always get

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.RestHandlerException: Request did not match expected format EmptyRequestBody.
```

I've tried that endpoint using Postman and Python and it works ok but not using c#. This is the code im trying with

```
var stream = File.OpenRead(jarPath);

var flinkClient = new HttpClient()
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("xxxx"),
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3000)
};

var content = new MultipartFormDataContent()
{
    { new StreamContent(stream), "jarfile", "test-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar"},
};

content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-java-archive");
var response = await flinkClient.PostAsync("jars/upload", content);
var resultContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I've also tried using the package RestClient with the same result

Comment: Have you tried to perform the same from Postman? Did it work?

Comment: This `-H "Expect:"` seems strange...

Comment: Also, have you tried to explicitly call the `Add` on `content` instead of relying on the  collection initializer?